# How to disable default archive name mask in batch

Tags: batch-file, winrar

WinRAR has the option "Generate archive name by mask". I Set this option to " - yyyy.mm.dd - hh.mm.ss". This is fine for most of the cases.

However, I have a windows batch file which creates zip archives using WinRAR:

**Example command:** winrar a -afzip -m3 -ep1 -y "E:\myarchive.zip" "E:\Temp\"

The result file is "myarchive - 2014.07.03 - 10.05.09.zip".

Is there any switch to ignore/disable the "Generate archive name by mask" option in the batch file? I found the switch "-ag" but I didn't manage to remove the archive name mask.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in the batch file either

```
WinRAR.exe a -afzip -ag- -m3 -ep1 -y "E:\myarchive.zip" "E:\Temp\"
```

or

```
WinRAR.exe a -afzip -cfg- -m3 -ep1 -y "E:\myarchive.zip" "E:\Temp\"
```

With switch `-ag-` the archive name mask in the default compression profile is disabled.

With switch `-cfg-` the default compression profile is completely ignored.

I tested both suggestions with WinRAR.exe v4.20 and v5.10 after changing first the default compression profile to ZIP compression with archive name mask `- yyyy.mm.dd - hh.mm.ss` and verifying by execution of your command line that indeed the ZIP file is created with name according to the mask in default compression profile.